# Extracting value of selected attribute from Laravel Eloquent ORM MySql query result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a variable that saves result of Elqouent ORM MySql query result as such:

```
 $from = DB::table('stops')
          ->select('id',)
          ->where('name','=',$data['from'])
          ->get();
```

So I wish to know what number is the ID attribute.
Result of query ($from variable contains) is following:

```
[{"id":7}]
```

Now how do I "extract" that number 7 into a variable? i.e $id = .... ?!?
Im not sure what kind of object or array or what that result is. Square brackets indicate array, curly maybe object ? I tried several ways to "get my hands on" that number but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: The results you are showing is `json`, it should be a `Collection`. Do you expect multiple results? More than one item with the same name and multiple id's?

Comment: @dbf expected is just a single item.

Comment: Instead of `get()` just use `first()`. Instead of a `Collection` you will get the item, just inspect the returned value with `dd($from)`.

Comment: @dbf when I switched get() with first() I receive error
`"TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given"
`

Comment: @dbf got it, had to add -> id also

Comment: Always debug your variables, how do you know when to use object notation `->` or array notation `[ ]`? You don't, so inspect your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use 'first()->id'

```
 $value = DB::table('stops')
          ->select('id',)
          ->where('name','=',$data['from'])
          ->first();
$result=null;
if($value!=null) $result=$value->id;
return $result;
```

Comment: And what if `first()` returns `null`?